# React-native Webview can not download image file from webpage

Tags: react-native, image

**Environment:**

**OS:** Android
**OS version:** Emulator API 34
**react-native version:** 0.71.11
**react-native-webview version:** 13.2.2

Hi,
I am using html file to create image and download.
These are my HTML Image creation java script.

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = "image.png";
      link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream")
      link.click();
      link.remove();
```

The site link is https://test.bdanam.com/index3.html?data=0
When I use mobile browser I can download the image but when I use the webview, I can not download the image.
From the site I take a picture and download to the mobile.

This is my React Native Webview Code.

```
<WebView
        source={{ uri: 'https://test.bdanam.com/index3.html?data=0' }}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        mixedContentMode={'always'}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
        allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
        allowFileAccess={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        {...platformProps}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
```

I can not download the image from React Native.
I follow this method. https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/example/examples/Downloads.tsx

**To Reproduce:**
Open the Webview from the site and take picture, no image start download. https://test.bdanam.com/index3.html?data=0
But from mobile browser can download.
[Capure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf6Yt.png)

My objective is to take a picture and download to the mobile device.

Comment: Any workaround found ?